# change height of combobox in winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, size

I'm developing an application for kind of touch screen device. In order be user friendly, I need to change size of combobox.

I've checked many thing including `DrawItemEventHandler` and `MeasureItemEventHandler`, but it didn't work as I want.

Basically I would like to change height of combobox without touching font size. When I change font size of combobox, it looks like left side of the image. 
How can I set my combobox which will look like right side of the image?

[image]

By the way, don't know if it's effect solution, I am not using array string. I'm binding data like.

```
 combobox.DisplayMember = "Name";
 combobox.ValueMember = "ID";
 combobox.DataSource = new BindingSource { DataSource = datalist };
```

Thanks in advance.

With TaW solution, I managed to set items as I want. The only thing I couldn't set text in middle when combobox items not droped down. How can I set this text position to the centre?

[image]

Comment: "...without touching font size. When I change font size..." I don't understand.

Comment: I mean, when I change size of "Font" property, combobox height changes itself. But I would like to change only height of combobox. Not size of font.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the `ItemHeight` property and then draw the items yourself in the `DrawItem` event.

Not terribly hard, search for 'ownerdraw' & 'combobox'. There is one example on [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1767/Implementing-an-OwnerDrawn-ComboBox)

Here is a minimal version, pulled from the above link:

```
private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Index < 0) return;
    Font f = comboBox1.Font;
    int yOffset = 10;

    if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Focus) == 0)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, e.Bounds);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(comboBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), f, Brushes.Black, 
                              new Point(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y + yOffset));
    }
    else
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, e.Bounds);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(comboBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), f, Brushes.White, 
                              new Point(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y + yOffset));
    }
```

}

You also have to set the `DropDownStyle` to `DropDownList` to get the highlighting to work and you need to set the `DrawMode` to `OwnerDrawFixed`. (Or to `OwnerDrawVariable`, if you want to have different heights for some itmes..)

Comment: Obviously you should rather use the system colors, see below and will want to adapt the yOffset to your Font- and ItemSize.


                SolidBrush backBrush = new SolidBrush(SystemColors.Window);


                SolidBrush fontBrush = new SolidBrush(SystemColors.WindowText);

                SolidBrush backBrush = new SolidBrush(SystemColors.Highlight);


                SolidBrush fontBrush = new SolidBrush(SystemColors.HighlightText);


                backBrush.Dispose();


                fontBrush.Dispose();

Comment: it worked. But I have one last question. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Hm, I'm not so sure now. I played around and found that my test combo always displays the text portion exactly like the item like it is cloning it. This includes font color position etc..
So I can't reproduce your result.
The post I quoted was about aligning the text, although it said that ownerdraw wouldn't help there.

Comment: well if its possible, somehow I need to set just after data bind. Because DrawItem event fires while selected item change.